# Read Azure Blob Async, Why the 2 Delays

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing a Azure Function that is triggered by a Storage Queue Messsage. Then it reads the blob line by line and will do some stuff with the data. The line itself is a Json line.

I assembled my code based on examples on the web, but I'm getting the impression that there is something wrong. I'm getting (in development on VS2017) 2 major delays. On the OpenReadAsync and on each ReadlineAsync...

So, if anybody has advice, I'm not a c# developer.

```
private static async Task ProcessFile(string fileName, ILogger log)
    {
        // Connect Source
        CloudStorageAccount cosmobatchStorageAccount = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageAccount(CommonCode.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComsoBatch_Storage"));
        CloudBlobClient cosmobatchBlobClient = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageClient(cosmobatchStorageAccount);
        CloudBlobContainer cosmobatchBlobContainer = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageContainer(cosmobatchBlobClient, CommonCode.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmoBatch_Container"));
        CloudBlockBlob cosmobatchBlob = cosmobatchBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        // Connect Destination
        CloudStorageAccount singlefileStorageAccount = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageAccount(CommonCode.GetEnvironmentVariable("SingleFile_Storage"));
        CloudBlobClient singlefileBlobClient = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageClient(singlefileStorageAccount);
        CloudBlobContainer singlefileBlobContainer = AzureBlobHandling.GetStorageContainer(singlefileBlobClient, CommonCode.GetEnvironmentVariable("SingleFile_Container"));
        //CloudBlockBlob singlefileBlob = cosmobatchBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        try
        {   // Read Blob
            log.LogInformation("Pass 1");
            using (Stream stream =  await cosmobatchBlob.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                log.LogInformation("Pass 2");
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Pass 3");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation("Pass 4");
                        string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                        if (line == null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                        jRecord jRec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jRecord>(line);
                        log.LogInformation(String.Format("MsgNbr : {0}, FileName : {1}, FileType {2}", jRec.msgnbr, jRec.filename, jRec.msgtype));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(String.Format("Catch: {0}", ex));
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is a "major delay"?

Comment: Like @StephenCleary asked: what is "major"? Could you provide us some numbers?

Comment: I was talking about 7 seconds of "waiting", but in the post below it's a bit explained. I was just a bit scary that my code did a step extra. But I've started it in the cloud. Works more then fast enough, almost no delays (<1sec). Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine the `OpenReadAsync` to take some time, since it

> Initiates an asynchronous operation to open a stream for reading from the blob.

*Source: [CloudBlockBlob.OpenReadAsync Method()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn451819(v%3Dazure.10))*

It's laying the groundwork to enable you to manipulate the blob using the `Stream`.

`ReadLineAsync`

> Reads a line of characters asynchronously from the current stream and returns the data as a string.

*Source: [StreamReader.ReadLineAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync)*

It's essentially a download. So if that's a huge line (which means a lot of data), it might take some time, too.

Also, please be advised that running code in debug mode slows it down. And of course this type of manipulation is slower on a local machine than running it in Azure since bandwidth (the speed of your connection) is a factor in this scenario.

If the numbers are in the (low-hundred) milliseconds, I wouldn't worry if I were you. Otherwise, you might want to have a look at the size of the data, and if a Blob is the best type of storage for this type of data.